# Sql Query Modification

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table called Customer with following schema.

```
    Create Table Customer(id Number,customer_type varchar(20),customer_status char(1),account_number varchar(20));
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'RETAIL','A','32456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'RETAIL','I','92456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'RETAIL','P','22456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'PERSONAL','A','42456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'PERSONAL','I','52456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(123,'PERSONAL','P','62456798');
    Insert into Customer(id,customer_type,customer_status,account_number)values(243,'PERSONAL','A','02456798');
    commit;
```

I am trying get Id where customer status is active.Customer_type can be of two types **RETAIL** or **PERSONAL**.I just want return Retail true if id have any active reatils accounts else false,
same with **Personal** 
I tried below query but i have trouble returning id

```
select REATIL,PERSONAL from (select  case  when customer_status = 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end as REATIL from Customer where customer_status='A' and customer_type='RETAIL')
,(select  id, case  when customer_status = 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end as PERSONAL from Customer where customer_status='A' and customer_type='PERSONAL');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|      id             |     Retail       |     Personal   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|       123           |         Y        |   Y            |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|      243            |        N         |    Y           |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
```

[image]

Ay help would be appreciated.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and expected result as tabular text (not image)

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (make modifications as per your further requirements). I did this as per given data but I feel that the data is not broad enough to test the code. And I made some assumptions as putting blank when there is no match.

Basically to determine whether Retail is Y or N, I used a case statement and did the same for Personal

**-- This solution didn't fit as the OP needs 1 record per ID**

```
select  ID, 
        Case When customer_type = 'RETAIL' and customer_status = 'A' then 'Y'   
            When customer_type = 'RETAIL' and customer_status != 'A' then 'N' 
            Else ''
        End as Retail,
        Case When customer_type = 'PERSONAL' and customer_status = 'A' then 'Y'   
            When customer_type = 'PERSONAL' and customer_status != 'A' then 'N' 
            Else ''
        End as PERSONAL,
        account_number
from  Customer
```

**Here is the required solution**

```
Select ID, Max(RETAIL) as RETAIL, Max(PERSONAL) as PERSONAL 
from
(
select ID, 
        Case When customer_type = 'RETAIL' and customer_status = 'A' then 'Y'   
            When customer_type = 'RETAIL' and customer_status != 'A' then 'N' 
            Else ''
        End as Retail,
        Case When customer_type = 'PERSONAL' and customer_status = 'A' then 'Y'   
            When customer_type = 'PERSONAL' and customer_status != 'A' then 'N' 
            Else ''
        End as PERSONAL
from  Customer
) Q
Group by ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you see my expected it returns only one row for given id even it have multiple accounts.

Comment: The Distinct keyword is not necessary (I will edit to remove that)

Answer (score 0):

try using a join.
the following query returns the account number instead of 'Y'

```sql
select C.id, max(R.account_number), max(P.account_number) from Customer C
    left join Customer R on R.id = c.id
    left join Customer P on P.id = c.id
    where   R.customer_type = 'RETAIL'   
        and R.customer_status = 'A' 
        and P.customer_type = 'PERSONAL' 
        and P.customer_status = 'A'
    group by C.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you see my expected it returns only one row for given id even it have multiple accounts.

Comment: just group the result